# PHP session variable won't change

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication, login-attempts

**UPDATE** : I added all codes;

I want to create a login page for test purpose and I included attempt number with php sessions. The problem is session's variable isn't changing.

```html
index.php

<?php 
 
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['attempt']=3;
 }

 if ($_SESSION['attempt']<0){
  header('location:login_error.php');
 }

 require('../function/start.php'); 
 $title = 'Login';
 require('../template/header.php');

 $ip = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

 var_dump($_SESSION['attempt'])
?>

<h3 class="epad_header">Login</h3>

<div id="epad_wrapper">
 <div id="ad_form_wrapper">

  <form action="control.php" method="POST">
   <fieldset>
    <span class="formtext">ID</span>
    <input type="text" name="epadName" id="epadName" required>
    <span class="formtext">Pass</span>
    <input type="password" name="epadPass" id="epadPass" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Ok" class="formbuton" name="formbuton">
    <br>
    <span class="formtext">IP Adress : <?php echo $ip; ?></span>
    <br>
    <span class="formtext">Attempt : <?php echo $_SESSION['attempt'] ?></span>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>

<?php require('../template/footer.php'); ?>
```

```html
control.php

<?php
 
 if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
    }
 require('../function/start.php'); 
 $title = 'Control';

 if (isset($_POST['formbuton'])){
  $name = htmlentities($_POST['epadName']);
  $pwd = htmlentities($_POST['epadPass']);
 }

 $check = $db->prepare('SELECT user, pass FROM users');
 $check->execute();

 $result = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 $user = $result['user'];
 $pass = $result['pass'];
 

 if ($name == $user && $pwd == $pass ){
  $_SESSION['name']= $name;
      header("location:main.php");
     }else{
  $_SESSION['attempt']--;
  header('location:index.php');
 }

?>
```

- when a user enter the page(first visit) ; a session will be started, and attempt variable will be created. (index.php)
- If they enter false data attempt variable will be decreased. (control.php)
- if there are 3 failed attempt page will redirects to login_error.page (index.php)

First Problem : Session variable is not changing.

Second Problem: Even If I enter correct data, the page directs to index.php (login area) instead of main.php

Comment: Show the complete codes, not just the codes you think are relevant.

Comment: did you do `session_start()` ?

Comment: Do you have any `session_start()` in your control.php? Hard to know with just some snippets.

Comment: Any script that uses `$_SESSION` **must** start with a `session_start()`

Comment: Also, the number of attempts is reset to 3 every time they go to the login page. You should be starting the session, and then checking if `$_SESSION['attempt']` is set.

Comment: You need to use a `where` clause or iterate over all the records (not the best way but `while ($result = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`. As is you only are looking at the first record in the DB. Also your passwords should be hashed.

Comment: there is session_start line in if statement. @chris85 thank you for advice, yes! you are right but there is just one record in the table also security is not important at the moment. It's just for testing.

Answer (score 1):

try to place `session_start();` at the first line, after `<?php`

Comment: at the first line after <?php

Comment: if you take a look first lines, you will see there are session_start() code in if statement.

Comment: i mean change from if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['attempt']=3;
 } to session_start(); if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  
  $_SESSION['attempt']=3;
 }

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem;

Actually I don't understand why

```
if(!isset($_SESSION){session_start; $_SESSION['attempt']=3;}
```

didn't work but when I modified this code to that code

```
session_start;
if (!isset($_SESSION['attempt']){$_SESSION['attempt']=3;}
```

Anyway, thank you for reading.